# Is it possible to running sql file with parameter and getting result set?

Tags: java, sql, oracle, toad

Hi dear stackoverflow users,

Firstly,i want to specify that my platforms are JAVA, ORACLE and TOAD.
I have some SELECT queries that include parameters and i have stored them in properties file to make them more readable. I can use them with '?' and setTYPE in JAVA.

But i have to use (:) operator to define parameters in TOAD. So, when i want to run my query in TOAD, i copy the query from JAVA properties file and paste it to TOAD editor and add parameters manuelly. This is not professional i think. I want to store my queries with : operator and in JAVA platform. Is this possible ? Are there any framework or something like it ?

NOTE :

1-) i want to store my queries with my JAVA code, not in stored procedure.

2-) i want to store my queries that can run that two platform without change anything.

Thank you.

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28765/addfunc.htm#TDPJD210

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [`OraclePreparedStatement`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e13995/oracle/jdbc/OraclePreparedStatement.html):

```
String query = myProperties.getProperty("some_key");
//Suppose query is 'SELECT * FROM MY_TBL WHERE ID=:myId'

OraclePreparedStatement statement = (OraclePreparedStatement) myConnection.prepareStatement(query);

statement.setStringAtName("myId", "abc2");

someResultSet = statement.executeQuery();
```

Comment: Thanks. im looking for this.